# Asp.Net core 3.1 MVC application after publishing login form stuck

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I just finished publishing my MVC app to manage scheduling and work times of my company employees.
I published it to a test VM with Windows 2019 and IIS and Net Core hosting via web deploy.

During testing in Visual Studio this issue never occurred.

I open the :80 port of the target vm and try to do the login using the identity framework. In visual studio works like a charm...

In production environment essentially after I log in with correct credentials chrome just stays in login page with the page loading circle spinning and at the bottom reporting that it's "elaborating the request" whatever that means...

I left it there and there was no timeout even... 5 min straight... and the weird thing is if I stop the page and reload on one of the role limited pages it says I'm logged in correctly...

Don't know what could be the cause of this... it's a completely stock implementation of the identity framework...

Any ideas?

[image]

**EDIT** after I update the page and force it to go to the redirect destination subsequent logout and login, **WITHOUT** closing the chrome tab I'm in, are working! what does that mean? is it some kind of cookie situation?

**EDIT** I changed the return of this code:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

    //
    //  Redirect to user's dashboard home page
    //

    return RedirectToAction("AddUserRecord", "UserRecordAdministration", new { Area = "Dashboard" }); //RedirectToPage("/Main/Home", new { Area = "Dashboard" });
}
```

to this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

    //
    //  Redirect to user's dashboard home page
    //

    return Page();
}
```

and it does infact reload the same login page... so the code gets to this part of the program it just doesn't know what the heck to do with a redirect to action in a different area I suppose...

Comment: Check error logs in VM? Missing database?

Comment: @BradPatton no database is present. also user is there correctly assigned to it's role and with a set password. as I said the login procedure is actually working it just doesn't complete the redirection after the login is complete...

Comment: So possibly the page being redirected to isn't responding. Would recommend adding logging code to the login process and the redirect page and see exactly where the process is breaking

Comment: but I can load that destination page! that is the bit I don't get!

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Home", "Main", new { Area = "Dashboard" });

Comment: I just do this when I see that the result of the signInManager is succeded nothing more and in  development locally in VS2019 it works perfectly

Comment: I don't know the solution to your specific problem just how I would debug in general. Maybe the destination is being reached but failing to return or maybe it's not being reached at all. I would add logging and see how far it gets. If it works in dev I would also double check all of the config files to see if there are differences once you deploy. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219276/discussion-between-fabio-bologna-and-brad-patton).